# neo4j apoc.export.csv permission denied error

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to use `apoc.export.csv`

My query is as follows:

`call apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH (a) Return id(a) limit 5", "test.csv", {} )`

but i get this error:

`Failed to invoke procedure 'apoc.export.csv.query': Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.csv (Permission denied)`

I have the following set in `neo4j.conf`

`apoc.export.file.enabled=true
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.export.*`

any hints would be appreciated

Answer (score 6):

exporting to `/tmp/filename` worked!

Comment: This also worked for me when I got the error "Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.export.csv.all` ...(Read-only file system)"